# turn-by-turn navigation with google maps url scheme swift

Tags: swift

How can I enable turn-by-turn navigation with google maps urlscheme?. I used below url in swift

```
comgooglemaps://?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f&directionsmode=driving
```

but it only creates a **route**, the start navigation button is not present when the google maps app is activated.

am i missing something?

```
let kGoogleMapsSchema = "comgooglemaps://"
    let path = "\(kGoogleMapsSchema)?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f&directionsmode=driving"

    guard let finalURLString = String(format: path, currentUserCoordinates!.latitude, currentUserCoordinates!.longitude, destinationCoordinates!.latitude, destinationCoordinates!.longitude, currentUserCoordinates!.latitude, currentUserCoordinates!.longitude).addingPercentEncoding(
        withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else {
            return
    }

    guard let url = URL(string: finalURLString) else {
        return
    }

    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
```

am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer as only preview button was available instead of start navigation. Because I was giving start coordinates not of my current location. So in case it is my current coordinates it will work.

[Google Maps, No Option for Starting the Navigation, Only Preview is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777562/google-maps-no-option-for-starting-the-navigation-only-preview-is-there/21907575)